# Why does CapForm behave strange with different options?

Tags: graphics

This CapForm works well:

```
Graphics[{CapForm["Square"], Thickness[.1], Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]},
  PlotRange -> 1.5, PlotLabel -> "Square"]
```

[image]

However, if you change `Thickness` to `0.5` you would get a strange cap like this.

```
Graphics[{CapForm["Square"], Thickness[.5], Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]},
  PlotRange -> 1.5, PlotLabel -> "Square"]
```

[image]

Or if you remove `PlotRange` or change it then you would get a strange cap as well.

```
Graphics[{CapForm["Square"], Thickness[.1], Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]},
  PlotLabel -> "Square"]
```

[image]

EDIT: I don't need to reopen this as the problem is already solved.
However, still wonder why people think this is offtopic. Is it easy to to find from docs? No, unless you already knew it.

Comment: Caps look strange because part of them are outside the frame. Use larger ``PlotRange`` to get back the normal picture: ``Graphics[{CapForm["Square"], Thickness[.5], Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]}, PlotRange -> 5, PlotLabel -> "Square"]``.

Comment: Wonder why some people voted to close it. It's just obvious  only if you ALREADY know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs:

`Thickness[r]`
is a graphics directive which specifies that lines which follow are to be drawn with thickness r. The thickness r is given as a **fraction of the horizontal plot range**.

---

Use `Frame->True` to see where clipping starts:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{CapForm["Square"]
   , Thickness[t]
   , Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]}
  , PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}
  , PlotLabel -> "Square"
  , Frame -> True
  ]
 , {{t, 0.3, "Thickness"}, 0.1, 0.8}
 ]
```

A better way would be to experiment with `AbsoluteThickness`.

**EDIT**

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   CapForm["Square"]
   , Thickness[t]
   , Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]
   , AbsoluteThickness[a]
   , Red
   , Line[{{-5, -5}, {5, 5}}]
   }
  , PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}
  , PlotLabel -> "Square"
  , Frame -> True
  ]
 , {{t, 0.3, "Thickness"}, 0.1, 0.8, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , {{a, 2, "AbsoluteThickness"}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to see the problem.

Comment: Same is the case with `PointSize` and `AbsolutePointSize`.

Answer (score 2):

If you execute

```
Graphics[{CapForm["Square"], Thickness[.1], Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Square"]
```

which is your first command with a different `PlotRange` you get the following:

[image: p1]

which demonstrates some weird behaviour. So, we narrowed down the problem. For example if you try

```
Graphics[{CapForm["Square"], Thickness[.5], Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]},
  PlotRange -> 3.5, PlotLabel -> "Square"]
```

you obtain

[image: p2]

without any peculiar edges.

Comment: I did but this doesn't explain the reason why it didn't work.

Comment: The answer lies in `Thickness`, please see the answer by @Syed. I think it does not make much sense to repeat said explanation :-)